# Laptop CPU stuck at 800Mhz randomly but works again when unplugged

Tags: ubuntu, performance, cpu-frequency

I have a `Dell Precision 7550` with an `Intel Xeon W-10885M` (8 cores, 16 threads) that has been displaying a strange behavior lately. I have a dual boot between `Windows 10` and `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS` with `uname -r`  being `5.15.0-46-generic` and I haven't been noticing any problem on Windows 10. On top of that, I have the following installed on Ubuntu:

```
cpufrequtils/focal,now 008-1.1 amd64
cpuid/focal,now 20200211-1 amd64
cpuidtool/focal,now 0.4.1-1.1 amd64
cpuinfo/focal,now 0.0~git20190201.d5e37ad-2 amd64
cpupower-gui/focal,now 0.7.2-2 amd64
indicator-cpufreq/focal,focal,now 0.2.2-0ubuntu3 all
libcpufreq0/focal,now 008-1.1 amd64
libcpuid14/focal,now 0.4.1-1.1 amd64
libcpuinfo0/focal,now 0.0~git20190201.d5e37ad-2 amd64
thermald/focal-updates,now 1.9.1-1ubuntu0.6 amd64
```

and you can find a list of the running services (and the inactivated, etc) at the end of this post. I haven't installed `cpupower` because I do not seem to manage to find it in the public repositories. I haven't installed `cpufreqd`. Also, I have deactivated `laptop-mode-tools` because I found that it was causing problems.

---

**THE PROBLEM:** When I start my laptop computer on Ubuntu, there is no problem with the CPU clock, it gets adjusted depending on the task. But after a while, a little bit at random, it suddenly get stuck at `800Mhz` (lowest setting) and there is nothing I can do to bring it back to higher frequencies... apart just unplugging it to put it on battery. As soon as I unplug it, the CPU frequency gets adjusted on demand again. If I plug it again, it continue to work properly. **At first it seemed completely random but I can seem to reproduce the problem when I play youtube videos using either firefox or chromium. After some time playing videos, the CPU will get stuck at `800Mhz`.** So far, I haven't reproduced the problem by running intense benchmarks like sysbench (but I haven't tested a lot).

When it happens `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_max_freq` stays the same (`5300000`) and `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_min_freq` stays the same also (`800000`). And when it's stuck at `800Mhz` if I change "manually" the governor to `powersave` or `performance`, the CPU remains stuck at `800Mhz` (the only thing that seems to work seems to be unplugging it (or restarting the computer, of course)). The driver that `cpufreq` is using is `intel_pstate` so as explained [here](https://www.grid5000.fr/w/CPU_parameters#intel_pstate_driver) `powersave` corresponds to `ondemand` (CPU frequency is adjusted) while `performance` sets the CPU frequency to its maximum.

I tried to uninstall `thermald`, but the problem still happened, so it's not coming from there.

C-States are deactivated in the BIOS, Intel Speedstep is activated, and TurboMode is enabled. Again, everything seems to work fine when I boot on Windows 10.

**UPDATE:** **The problem does not seem to happen when the laptop in on battery.** It's only happening when it's plugged in. However I tried with 2 different DELL chargers, and it keeps happening in both cases, **so it does not depend on the charger.**

Also, there has recently been updates for both the Linux kernel and the BIOS. I do not know if the problem is related to one of these updates. The only thing I know is that the problem does not seem to happen on Windows.

---

**QUESTION:** How to solve the problem? What process is putting my CPU to its lowest setting? What tests can I do to better understand what is going on? What could be causing that?

---

```
  UNIT                                    LOAD      ACTIVE   SUB     DESCRIPTION                   
  accounts-daemon.service                 loaded    active   running Accounts Service              
  acpid.service                           loaded    active   running ACPI event daemon             
  alsa-restore.service                    loaded    active   exited  Save/Restore Sound Card State 
  alsa-state.service                      loaded    inactive dead    Manage Sound Card State (restore and store)                                     
  anacron.service                         loaded    inactive dead    Run anacron jobs              
  apache2.service                         loaded    active   running The Apache HTTP Server        
  apparmor.service                        loaded    active   exited  Load AppArmor profiles        
  apport-autoreport.service               loaded    inactive dead    Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled                       
  apport.service                          loaded    active   exited  LSB: automatic crash report generation                                          
  apt-daily-upgrade.service               loaded    inactive dead    Daily apt upgrade and clean activities                                          
  apt-daily.service                       loaded    inactive dead    Daily apt download activities 
  atd.service                             loaded    active   running Deferred execution scheduler  
● auditd.service                          not-found inactive dead    auditd.service                
  avahi-daemon.service                    loaded    active   running Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack       
  binfmt-support.service                  loaded    active   exited  Enable support for additional executable binary formats                         
  bluetooth.service                       loaded    active   running Bluetooth service             
  bolt.service                            loaded    active   running Thunderbolt system service    
  clamav-freshclam.service                loaded    active   running ClamAV virus database updater 
● cloud-config.service                    not-found inactive dead    cloud-config.service          
● cloud-init-local.service                not-found inactive dead    cloud-init-local.service      
  colord.service                          loaded    active   running Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles                                     
● connman.service                         not-found inactive dead    connman.service               
● console-screen.service                  not-found inactive dead    console-screen.service        
  console-setup.service                   loaded    active   exited  Set console font and keymap   
  cpufrequtils.service                    loaded    active   exited  LSB: set CPUFreq kernel parameters                                              
  cron.service                            loaded    active   running Regular background program processing daemon                                    
  cups-browsed.service                    loaded    active   running Make remote CUPS printers available locally                                     
  cups.service                            loaded    active   running CUPS Scheduler                
  dbus.service                            loaded    active   running D-Bus System Message Bus      
  dmesg.service                           loaded    inactive dead    Save initial kernel messages after boot                                         
  dundee.service                          loaded    active   running DUN service                   
  e2scrub_all.service                     loaded    inactive dead    Online ext4 Metadata Check for All Filesystems                                  
  e2scrub_reap.service                    loaded    inactive dead    Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots                               
  emergency.service                       loaded    inactive dead    Emergency Shell               
  etc-setserial.service                   loaded    active   exited  controls configuration of serial ports                                          
● exim4.service                           not-found inactive dead    exim4.service                 
  fam.service                             loaded    active   running LSB: File Alteration Monitor  
● fancontrol.service                      masked    inactive dead    fancontrol.service            
  fstrim.service                          loaded    inactive dead    Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab                            
● fwupd-refresh.service                   loaded    failed   failed  Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd                                          
  fwupd.service                           loaded    active   running Firmware update daemon        
  gdm.service                             loaded    active   running GNOME Display Manager         
  getty-static.service                    loaded    inactive dead    getty on tty2-tty6 if dbus and logind are not available                         
  getty@tty1.service                      loaded    inactive dead    Getty on tty1                 
  gpu-manager.service                     loaded    inactive dead    Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes                      
  grub-common.service                     loaded    inactive dead    Record successful boot for GRUB                                                 
  grub-initrd-fallback.service            loaded    inactive dead    GRUB failed boot detection    
  hddtemp.service                         loaded    active   exited  LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon                                         
  hv-fcopy-daemon.service                 loaded    inactive dead    Hyper-V File Copy Protocol Daemon                                               
  hv-kvp-daemon.service                   loaded    inactive dead    Hyper-V KVP Protocol Daemon   
  hv-vss-daemon.service                   loaded    inactive dead    Hyper-V VSS Protocol Daemon   
  irqbalance.service                      loaded    active   running irqbalance daemon             
● kbd.service                             not-found inactive dead    kbd.service                   
  kerneloops.service                      loaded    active   running Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures                
  keyboard-setup.service                  loaded    active   exited  Set the console keyboard layout                                                 
  kmod-static-nodes.service               loaded    active   exited  Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel                       
● laptop-mode.service                     loaded    failed   failed  Laptop Mode Tools             
  lm-sensors.service                      loaded    active   exited  Initialize hardware monitoring sensors                                          
  lmt-poll.service                        loaded    inactive dead    Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service                                     
  loadcpufreq.service                     loaded    active   exited  LSB: Load kernel modules needed to enable cpufreq scaling                       
  logrotate.service                       loaded    inactive dead    Rotate log files              
  man-db.service                          loaded    inactive dead    Daily man-db regeneration     
  memcached.service                       loaded    active   running memcached daemon              
  modprobe@drm.service                    loaded    inactive dead    Load Kernel Module drm        
  motd-news.service                       loaded    inactive dead    Message of the Day            
  mysql.service                           loaded    active   running MySQL Community Server        
  nas.service                             loaded    active   exited  LSB: start or stop the Network Audio System.                                    
  netplan-ovs-cleanup.service             loaded    inactive dead    OpenVSwitch configuration for cleanup                                           
  networkd-dispatcher.service             loaded    active   running Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd                                          
● NetworkManager-wait-online.service      loaded    failed   failed  Network Manager Wait Online   
  NetworkManager.service                  loaded    active   running Network Manager               
  ntp-systemd-netif.service               loaded    inactive dead    ntp-systemd-netif.service     
  ntp.service                             loaded    active   running Network Time Service          
  nvidia-persistenced.service             loaded    active   running NVIDIA Persistence Daemon     
● nvidia-powerd.service                   loaded    failed   failed  nvidia-powerd service         
● oem-config.service                      not-found inactive dead    oem-config.service            
  ofono.service                           loaded    active   running Telephony service             
  ondemand.service                        loaded    inactive dead    Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor                                          
  openvpn.service                         loaded    active   exited  OpenVPN service               
● ovsdb-server.service                    not-found inactive dead    ovsdb-server.service          
  phpsessionclean.service                 loaded    inactive dead    Clean php session files       
  plymouth-quit-wait.service              loaded    inactive dead    Hold until boot process finishes up                                             
  plymouth-quit.service                   loaded    inactive dead    Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen                                                  
  plymouth-read-write.service             loaded    inactive dead    Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data                                         
  plymouth-start.service                  loaded    inactive dead    Show Plymouth Boot Screen     
  polkit.service                          loaded    active   running Authorization Manager         
  postfix.service                         loaded    inactive dead    Postfix Mail Transport Agent  
● postfix@-.service                       loaded    failed   failed  Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)                                       
  pppd-dns.service                        loaded    inactive dead    Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down
  rc-local.service                        loaded    inactive dead    /etc/rc.local Compatibility   
  rescue.service                          loaded    inactive dead    Rescue Shell                  
  resolvconf-pull-resolved.service        loaded    inactive dead    resolvconf-pull-resolved.service                                                
  resolvconf.service                      loaded    active   exited  Nameserver information manager                                                  
  rpcbind.service                         loaded    active   running RPC bind portmap service      
  rsync.service                           loaded    inactive dead    fast remote file copy program daemon                                            
  rsyslog.service                         loaded    active   running System Logging Service        
  rtkit-daemon.service                    loaded    active   running RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service                                           
  saslauthd.service                       loaded    active   exited  LSB: saslauthd startup script 
  secureboot-db.service                   loaded    inactive dead    Secure Boot updates for DB and DBX                                              
● sendmail.service                        not-found inactive dead    sendmail.service              
● sep5.service                            loaded    failed   failed  systemd script to load sep5 driver at boot time                                 
  setserial.service                       loaded    active   exited  controls configuration of serial ports                                          
  setvtrgb.service                        loaded    active   exited  Set console scheme            
  snapd.apparmor.service                  loaded    active   exited  Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd                              
  snapd.autoimport.service                loaded    inactive dead    Auto import assertions from block devices                                       
  snapd.core-fixup.service                loaded    inactive dead    Automatically repair incorrect owner/permissions on core devices                
  snapd.failure.service                   loaded    inactive dead    Failure handling of the snapd snap                                              
  snapd.recovery-chooser-trigger.service  loaded    inactive dead    Wait for the Ubuntu Core chooser trigger                                        
  snapd.seeded.service                    loaded    active   exited  Wait until snapd is fully seeded                                                
  snapd.service                           loaded    active   running Snap Daemon                   
  snapd.snap-repair.service               loaded    inactive dead    Automatically fetch and run repair assertions                                   
  sndiod.service                          loaded    active   running sndio audio and MIDI server   
● sssd.service                            not-found inactive dead    sssd.service                  
  switcheroo-control.service              loaded    active   running Switcheroo Control Proxy service                                                
  systemd-ask-password-console.service    loaded    inactive dead    Dispatch Password Requests to Console                                           
  systemd-ask-password-plymouth.service   loaded    inactive dead    Forward Password Requests to Plymouth                                           
  systemd-ask-password-wall.service       loaded    inactive dead    Forward Password Requests to Wall        
  systemd-binfmt.service                  loaded    inactive dead    Set Up Additional Binary Formats                                                
  systemd-boot-system-token.service       loaded    inactive dead    Store a System Token in an EFI Variable                                         
  systemd-fsck-root.service               loaded    active   exited  File System Check on Root Device                                                  
  systemd-fsckd.service                   loaded    inactive dead    File System Check Daemon to report status                                       
  systemd-hwdb-update.service             loaded    inactive dead    Rebuild Hardware Database     
  systemd-initctl.service                 loaded    inactive dead    initctl Compatibility Daemon  
  systemd-journal-flush.service           loaded    active   exited  Flush Journal to Persistent Storage                                             
  systemd-journald.service                loaded    active   running Journal Service               
  systemd-logind.service                  loaded    active   running Login Service                 
  systemd-machine-id-commit.service       loaded    inactive dead    Commit a transient machine-id on disk                                           
  systemd-modules-load.service            loaded    active   exited  Load Kernel Modules           
  systemd-networkd.service                loaded    inactive dead    Network Service               
  systemd-pstore.service                  loaded    inactive dead    Platform Persistent Storage Archival                                            
  systemd-quotacheck.service              loaded    inactive dead    File System Quota Check       
  systemd-random-seed.service             loaded    active   exited  Load/Save Random Seed         
  systemd-remount-fs.service              loaded    active   exited  Remount Root and Kernel File Systems                                            
  systemd-resolved.service                loaded    active   running Network Name Resolution       
  systemd-rfkill.service                  loaded    inactive dead    Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status                                                 
  systemd-sysctl.service                  loaded    active   exited  Apply Kernel Variables        
  systemd-sysusers.service                loaded    active   exited  Create System Users           
● systemd-timesyncd.service               masked    inactive dead    systemd-timesyncd.service     
  systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service          loaded    inactive dead    Cleanup of Temporary Directories                                                
  systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service      loaded    active   exited  Create Static Device Nodes in /dev                                              
  systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service          loaded    active   exited  Create Volatile Files and Directories                                           
  systemd-udev-trigger.service            loaded    active   exited  udev Coldplug all Devices     
  systemd-udevd.service                   loaded    active   running udev Kernel Device Manager    
● systemd-update-done.service             not-found inactive dead    systemd-update-done.service   
  systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service    loaded    inactive dead    Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes                                       
  systemd-update-utmp.service             loaded    active   exited  Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown                                          
  systemd-user-sessions.service           loaded    active   exited  Permit User Sessions          
● systemd-vconsole-setup.service          not-found inactive dead    systemd-vconsole-setup.service                                                  
  thermald.service                        loaded    active   running Thermal Daemon Service        
  timidity.service                        loaded    active   exited  LSB: start and stop timidity  
● tlp.service                             masked    inactive dead    tlp.service                   
● ua-auto-attach.service                  not-found inactive dead    ua-auto-attach.service        
  ua-reboot-cmds.service                  loaded    inactive dead    Ubuntu Advantage reboot cmds  
  ua-timer.service                        loaded    inactive dead    Ubuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs                                
● ubuntu-advantage-cloud-id-shim.service  not-found inactive dead    ubuntu-advantage-cloud-id-shim.service                                          
  ubuntu-advantage.service                loaded    inactive dead    Ubuntu Advantage GCP Auto Attach Daemon                                         
  udisks2.service                         loaded    active   running Disk Manager                  
  ufw.service                             loaded    active   exited  Uncomplicated firewall        
  unattended-upgrades.service             loaded    active   running Unattended Upgrades Shutdown  
  upower.service                          loaded    active   running Daemon for power management   
  user-runtime-dir@1000.service           loaded    active   exited  User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000                                           
  user-runtime-dir@125.service            loaded    active   exited  User Runtime Directory /run/user/125                                            
  user@1000.service                       loaded    active   running User Manager for UID 1000     
  user@125.service                        loaded    active   running User Manager for UID 125      
  uuidd.service                           loaded    inactive dead    Daemon for generating UUIDs   
● walinuxagent.service                    not-found inactive dead    walinuxagent.service          
  whoopsie.service                        loaded    active   running crash report submission daemon                                                  
  wpa_supplicant.service                  loaded    active   running WPA supplicant                
● zfs-mount.service                       not-found inactive dead    zfs-mount.service             

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.
```

Comment: Are there any BIOS updates available for it?